# IE9 always runs in IE7 Compatibility mode

Tags: asp.net, .net, web, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9

I have a simple page in asp.net vs2008, when run in IE 9, the compatibility view button is visible, when clicked, the web page always run in IE7 compatibility mode.

Why the page does not does run in IE8, when compatibility view button is clicked? Do we even have IE8 compatibility view?

Here is the html code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text="Testing"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: IE 9 behavior]

Comment: Are you in a company?  They may have forced internet explorer to run locally in compatibility view through group policy.

Comment: By the way, your image clearly says IE9 compatibility view, and IE7 standards mode.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

***Step 1:Turn off compatibility view and check.***

- Open internet explorer.
- Click on Alt key on the keyboard. Now click on Tools in menu bar.
- Select Compatibility View Settings.
- Remove the check mark for Display all websites in Compatibility View 
  and close the Compatibility View Settings window.

***Step 2: Reset internet explorer settings and check.***

Fore more information refer : [Microsoft link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/923737)