# IE9 going into IE7 compatibility view even with X-UA meta tag

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-7, doctype, x-ua-compatible

So as per title, I'm using the `X-UA-Compatible` meta tag to force standards mode in the current IE version. (HTML below)

Despite this, in IE9 it goes into compatibility mode on percentage of users machines. I use Mac and it works fine on a Win7 IE9 virtual machine and also on my Windows machine's IE9. But when I test on a colleague's laptop it goes straight into compatibility view.

I've tried the following meta tags, without luck:

- `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7">`
- `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />`
- `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />`

I have tried resetting internet explorer settings using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22722381/ie9-always-runs-in-ie7-compatibility-mode) to the same question and it still doesn't work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7">
        <title>Site</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
...
```

Comment: Note: The site is not an intranet site

Comment: IIRC, using a conditional comment commits the parser to a version, so after that `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"` has no effect. Niklas Brunberg's answer avoids that because the real http header will be processed before the conditional comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft [specifies that a comma](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915(v=vs.85).aspx) should be used to separate each mode rather than the semicolon in your example snippet, as so:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9,8,7">
```

But I suspect that might be besides the point if you have already tried `content="IE=edge"` alone. A secondary solution would be to avoid the meta tag altogether and send X-UA-Compatible as an HTTP header instead.

And if that does not work, I would look into the network settings (not just IE's settings) in your colleague's laptop and see if his network is treated as an intranet despite it not being an intranet.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've changed the web servers headers using the code from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771258/whats-the-difference-if-meta-http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-edge-e#answer-8942455), and it appears to be working. I'm just going to do some final checks and if its fine I'll mark your answer as the best. Thank you for your help.